# Django admin for categories and objects

Tags: django, django-admin

I have `objects` and `catetories` in Django and `object` has `ForeignKey` to `Category`.

In Admin user must first create categories and then create objects choosing category from list.

What I want to have is file manager metaphore: User opens list of categories, clicks "create object here" and creates one like we do it with folders and files.

I wonder if Django has some application for it. Does it?

I know about inlines, but I do not want to edit object on the same page, I want to have list of them.

It is similar to [Django: adding an "Add new" button for a ForeignKey in a ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068168/django-adding-an-add-new-button-for-a-foreignkey-in-a-modelform) but I do not have `ModelForm`, I speak about admin

Comment: Your question is probably going to get closed as too broad or unclear, but I think what you're asking is a duplicate of [Django: adding an "Add new" button for a ForeignKey in a ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068168/django-adding-an-add-new-button-for-a-foreignkey-in-a-modelform)

Comment: The admin already does this for you...

Comment: @solarissmoke could you please give me example how django-admin does it?

Answer (score 1):

In Django admin, you can use inlines, example:

```
class OBJECTSInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OBJECTS
    extra = 0

class CATEGORYAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 10
    inlines = [OBJECTSInline,]

admin.site.register(CATEGORY, CATEGORYAdmin)
```

Comment: It will show edit forms for all items which is not what I was looking for..

Answer (score 1):

If you register both your models in the Django admin, you will see that when creating/editing an object with foreign key to Category, there will be a dropdown for the foreign key value, which lists existing values, and next to it, buttons for editing/deleting the selected value, or for creating a new Category:

[image: Screenshot of foreign key management utils in Django admin]

That seems to be what you're asking for - it's already there in the admin as soon as you register the relevant models.